# Change column from Pandas date object to python datetime

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have a dataset with the first column as date in the format: 2011-01-01 and `type(data_raw['pandas_date'])` gives me `pandas.core.series.Series`

I want to convert the whole column into date time object so I can extract and process year/month/day from each row as required.

I used `pd.to_datetime(data_raw['pandas_date'])` and it printed output with `dtype: datetime64[ns]` in the last line of the output. I assume that values were converted to datetime.

but when I run `type(data_raw['pandas_date'])` again, it still says `pandas.core.series.Series` and anytime I try to run `.dt` function on it, it gives me an error saying this is not a datetime object.

So, my question is - it looks like to_datetime function changed my data into datetime object, but how to I apply/save it to the pandas_date column? I tried

`data_raw['pandas_date'] = pd.to_datetime(data_raw['pandas_date'])`

but this doesn't work either, I get the same result when I check the type. Sorry if this is too basic.

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer is simply in the way you are checking the type of the dataframe. If I do :

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'date': ['2011-01-01','2011-01-02','2011-01-13']})
new = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])
type(new)
```

you will get the "overall" type of the object, which is a pandas series. But if you do:

```
new.dtypes
```

you get `dtype('<M8[ns]')`, the datetime object. This is because `dtypes` will list the type of data contained in each column of the dataframe, and type will only tell you that it is a dataframe.

Answer (score 0):

`type(data_raw['pandas_date'])` will always return `pandas.core.series.Series`, because the object `data_raw['pandas_date']` is of type `pandas.core.series.Series`. What you want is to get the `dtype`, so you could just do `data_raw['pandas_date'].dtype`.

> `data_raw['pandas_date'] = pd.to_datetime(data_raw['pandas_date'])`

This is correct, and if you do `data_raw['pandas_date'].dtype` again afterwards, you will see that it is `datetime[64]`.

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply. However when I use ```data_raw['pandas_date'].dtype``` to get the year out of it by typing: ```data_raw['pandas_date'].dtype.datetime.date.today().year``` it gives me the error ```'numpy.dtype' object has no attribute 'datetime'```. I am so confused lol

Comment: See my answer above. Using `import datetime as dt` get the year as `new.dt.year`. Also, extracting the year is a separate question. So if your original question has been answered, you should accept an answer and post the second question in a separate post